# Links when uploading

Tags: html, css

oHi i'm new to web design and am just wondering i have my site made and my links go as following

```
<li id="active"><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li> 

<li><a href="Lakes.html">Where to Fish</a></li>

<li><a href="specimenfish.html">Specimen Fish</a></li>

<li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>

<li><a href="Prebait.html">Pre Bait</a></li>
```

do i need to change them to site name .com when uploading to hosting site example below

```
<li><a href="www.sitename.com/Lakes.html">Where to Fish</a></li>
```

Specimen Fish

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your links (gallery.html, prebait.html, etc.) are in the same directory as the file containing those links, you're fine. It's called a relative URL - you don't need to specify the entire URL; you're navigating based on a shared parent directory.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to change them as long as they are in the same folder

**same folder**
`<li><a href="Lakes.html">Where to Fish</a></li>`

**next folder**
`<li><a href="folder_name/Lakes.html">Where to Fish</a></li>`

**one folder up**
`<li><a href="../Lakes.html">Where to Fish</a></li>`

**inside folder which is in one folder up**
`<li><a href="../folder_name/Lakes.html">Where to Fish</a></li>`

**direct URL** (if you want link to a file from certain folder on your server and it's too complex to do it with the previous examples - or if you want to link to file from another server)

`<li><a href="http://www.servername.com/folder/Lakes.html">Where to Fish</a></li>`

hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

use http:// at first of href, it means :

`<li><a href="www.sitename.com/Lakes.html">Where to Fish</a></li>`

must change to :

`<li><a href="http://www.sitename.com/Lakes.html">Where to Fish</a></li>`